# How to setup a group profile based for terminal server via LDAP?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ldap, cluster, terminal-server, roaming-profile

I have 4 terminal server "they are clustered together." All of them have the same specs and same configuration. and have Windows Server 2008 R2 installed on them. All users are using LDAP to log in. Also I am using roaming profiles for those users.

I have different groups of users that are using these terminal servers (each group is doing a different type of work so their needs are different.)

One group will need IE to be the default web browser. And a another group will need Google Chrome to be the default web browser. One group will need abc.com to be the home page and the other will need xyz.com to be the home page. One group will need different icons on the desktop than the other group. I hope the idea is clear now.

How can I create default template for each groups and when the user logs in the server knows what configuration template to use.

I appreciate you help and time.
and a big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your terminology like "using LDAP to log in" makes me think that you're not really very familiar with Windows Server. I think you'd do well to look at hiring an outside consultant to help you get this put together.

Active Directory Group Policy can do what you're looking for in a fairly simple manner. You'd create Organizational Units (OUs) to house the various user accounts (or, if you'd like a more complex configuration that leaves the current OU structure intact, Security Groups and filterng) and link Group Policy Objects (GPOs) to those OUs to apply the various settings you need.

This is pretty much a textbook case for Group Policy, however you'll need some background familiarity to make use of it effectively.

Edit:

Group Policy Preferences, which is a subset of Grouo Policy functionality, allows you to "target" settings selectively (based on Security Group membership or a whole host of other factors). You might be able to get away with a single GPO and this "Item-level Targeting" functionality versus using multiple GPOs.

Comment: Group Policy Preferences may be of great use here as well, since they can easily be setup to target specific user groups without creating a bunch of separate policies.

Comment: Worth mentioning, for sure.

Comment: Thank you Evan. you are right I am not an network guy and my knowledge is limited. I was looking for the correct approach to get the right person to do the Job. Another idea that came up also is to set a default profile for each group and link that profile for the users via Group Policies. I am still trying to research to see which is the best approach to do this.